# httpd: could not log pid to file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i have installed apache 2.0.65 in my Ubuntu 12.0 edition i couldn't start my apache server 
and it shows the error string not specified yet! 
any help please!
thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is still useful, and an answer about how to change the default pathname would be lovely here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does /usr/local/apache2/logs exist? If not, create it.  Also, it is unwise to use Apache 2.0.x in any kind of new environment -- it's EOL.

Comment: Wow! How dumb (even now & that's a different story) I was asking this question without checking the log file existence and version 

Comment: Or, change the log directory