# How to run httpd:2.4-alpine docker image not as root user

Tags: linux, docker, apache

I try to run **httpd:2.4-alpine** [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) not as a root user.

Default behavior :

```bash
> docker run -p 80:80 -d --rm --name httpd httpd:2.4-alpine
3c271ae8abfc3f54c0e63d62a2ce26fcbeeef29064da66f4b3f6bd00480ad4fb
> docker exec httpd --name httpd whoami
root
```

After looking inside the [Dockerfile definition](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/f3b7fd9c8ef59d1ad46c8b2a27df3e02d822834f/2.4/alpine/Dockerfile#L5) of this image, one can see a `www-data` is created with an id `82` :

```
...
RUN set -x \
    && adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data
# 82 is the standard uid/gid for "www-data" in Alpine
...
```

Let's try to run this image using this user then :

```bash
> docker stop httpd # cleaning previous instance
> docker run -p 80:80 --rm --name httpd -u www-data httpd:2.4-alpine
```

This failed with this error :

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
> qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName'
> directive globally to suppress this message AH00558: httpd: Could not
> reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using
> 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message [Tue Aug 30 15:57:25.958695 2022] [core:error] [pid 1:tid
> 140459379268424] (13)Permission denied: AH00099: could not create
> /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid.XXXXXX [Tue Aug 30 15:57:25.959029
> 2022] [core:error] [pid 1:tid 140459379268424] AH00100: httpd: could
> not log pid to file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21647437/3840700) that seems to fix the problem, but because I'm in a docker context I don't know how/if I can apply this solution.

Does someone out there know how I could run this image NOT as a root ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @javierlga's answer is correct, you don't need to build a new image to remediate this issue. There are three things we need to do:

1. Run Apache as the `www-data` user
2. Grant the `www-data` user the ability to bind to privileged ports, and
3. Deal with the need to write a pid file into `/usr/local/apache2/logs`.

We can accomplish (1) using the `-u` argument to `docker run`:

```
docker run -u www-data ...
```

We can solve (2) using with the `--cap-add`  argument to `docker run`:

```
docker run -u www-data --cap-add net_bind_service ...
```

That leaves us with (3). We can see the problem in the logs you posted in your question:

```
Permission denied: AH00099: could not create /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid.XXXXXX
```

Apache is trying to write a file into `/usr/local/apache2/logs`, but
the `www-data` user does not have permission to create files in this
directory.

There are a number of ways of solving this problem. The simplest is probably moving the pidfile to `/tmp`, which we can do by passing the necessary configuration directive to `httpd` using the `-C` command line option:

```
docker run ... docker.io/httpd:2.4.54-alpine \
  httpd-foreground -C 'PidFile /tmp/httpd.pid'
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
docker run -u www-data \
  --cap-add net_bind_service -p 8080:80 \
  docker.io/httpd:2.4.54-alpine \
  httpd-foreground -C 'PidFile /tmp/httpd.pid'
```

Or in a `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  httpd:
    image: docker.io/httpd:2.4.54-alpine
    command: [httpd-foreground, -C, "PidFile /tmp/httpd.pid"]
    user: www-data
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    cap_add:
      - net_bind_service
```

That runs without errors and does not require maintaining our own image.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that by default the user `www-data` lacks the capability to bind a privileged port, in fact, any other regular will have the same issue.

As you can see, only the parent process runs as the `root` user, and child processes run as the `www-data` user.

```
/usr/local/apache2 # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 httpd -DFOREGROUND
    8 www-data  0:00 httpd -DFOREGROUND
    9 www-data  0:00 httpd -DFOREGROUND
   10 www-data  0:00 httpd -DFOREGROUND
   92 root      0:00 sh
   98 root      0:00 ps aux
```

By setting `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep'` to the `httpd` binary, you'll be able to run it as the `www-data` user.

In order to fix this, you need to create a new image, this is a Dockerfile example:

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine

RUN apk add libcap && chown -hR www-data:www-data /usr/local/apache2/ && \
  setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd

USER www-data
```

Once you have created the new image, you'll be able to run the image as non-root.

Logs:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Aug 30 16:51:43.660323 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 281473523657800] AH00489: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 30 16:51:43.660358 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 281473523657800] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Running as:

```
/usr/local/apache2 $ whoami
www-data
```

Comment: Docker [sets the NET_BIND_SERVICE capability by default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) and you don't need to do this.  If you did need to, `docker run --cap-add` would be a more normal way to do this than running `setcap` in a Dockerfile.